# pandoc latex template

Tags: r, templates, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I have found this latex template,

http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/

which is perfect for my thesis. I am currently writing it directly in Latex with TexStudio, and playing around with the template directly is easy.
I am however switching to RStudio and wiriting it as a RNotebook, as I need to be able to easily produce docx versions of it (or other formats).
I already produced a Rmd version which works perfectly as a html/docx, but the pdf it produces (and i tried bookdown, thesisdown, oxfordown etc..) is never as good looking as the template above.

Is there a way to "extract" a template from the latex template in the link, which can be used for the pandoc conversion in RStudio? How?

(i am quite a newbie so please try with an easy accessible answer!)

Comment: sure, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates (If you don't need `R`, you can also just use `pandoc` directly on the commandline..)

Comment: Try sweave, it is a latex document that allows R code. In case you do not need R code run in the document and directly implemented in your pdf, I do not see a reason to leave TexStudio. You can insert code in plain Latex as well (but you are not able to run in on the go).

Comment: You could use the existing template directly: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#custom-templates-1. I am not sure it is worth the trouble, though.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. 

I need to change to RStudio because I indeed need to use some r code, and because I need to easily convert to html and word, which for the moment I am not able to do with TexStudio.

I had a look at those links, and yes they say you could use a template, but it is not clear How to make a template out of a formatted latex/pdf. I tried to set

pdf_document:
     template: mydocument.tex

But it did not work, printing out substantially the template document rather than the one I am working on with that style.